# What other words/phrases can I use in place of "train of thought"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Consider this hypothetical scenario,

> Person1: Front End software development does not require analytical ability.
> Person2: You are misinformed, I used to follow the same **train of thought/way of thinking**, but then I met a few front end developers, and I view front end development completely differently.

The construction "**train of thought/way of thinking**" feels very awkward to me, it does not seem like something a native English speaker would use.

Can somebody recommend a more idiomatic alternative?

Comment: *follow the same train of thought/way of thinking = **think the same***. More often, just *I used to **think that** [but now I think something different]*.

Answer (score 1):

Some decent alternatives might be:

> thought process, mentation, intellection

All of which are synonyms of "train of thought".